# Dynamic Route ExpressJS Based on link value

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm trying to set up some dynamic routing that pulls in the value from the selected link and pass it in my route before the name of the next page. For example:

I have a link on `'/'` and click on a link `<a href="#" id="solid-choice">Solid</a>`

I would like to pass in this link value into the route of the next page rendering. Like `'/solid/next-page'`

I have some routing set up, but I don't think it is properly pulling the route the way I wanted to. `/:pattern/next-page` is the route I'm talking about in particular

Here is my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    {{> head}}
</head>
<body class="pattern-wrapper">
{{> navigation}}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row pattern-choice">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2><i>Choose a pattern</i></h2>
                <ul>
                    <li class="button-border">
                        <h3 class="button-choice" ><a href=":pattern/next-page" class="button-link" id="solid-choice">SOLID</a></h3>
                    </li>
                    <li class="button-border">
                        <h3 class="button-choice" id="stripe-choice"><a href=":pattern/next-page" class="button-link" id="stripe-choice">STRIPE</a></h3>
                    </li>
                    <li class="button-border">
                        <h3 class="button-choice" id="plaid-choice"><a href=":pattern/next-page" class="button-link" id="plaid-choice">PLAID</a></h3>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my routing currently:

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('pages/index.hbs');
});

router.get(':pattern/next-page', function(req, res){
    req.param('pattern');
    res.render('pages/color.hbs');
});

router.get('/suit-result', function(req, res){
    res.render('pages/suit-result.hbs');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close. You need to make the pattern variable available to your template. You do that by changing `res.render('pages/color.hbs')` to `res.render('pages/color.hbs', {pattern: req.params.pattern})`.

Then you change the template to use the newly available variable: `<a href="{{pattern}}/next-step"></a>`

Comment: Hey @Ryan, thank you for your answer. I made you changes, but when I click on the link it brings me to localhost:3000/next-page, but a `404` error page not found and omits the `{{pattern}}`. Are these the correct changes? `router.get('/:pattern/next-page', function(req, res){
 res.render('pages/color.hbs', {
  pattern: req.params.pattern
 });
});`



`<a href="{{pattern}}/suit-color">Solid</a>`

Comment: Actually this is slightly more complicated than I originally thought. When someone clicks on a step, shouldn't that change which steps are available for them to click?

Comment: The value of that link that is being clicks should be the value getting passed to `{{pattern}}` so in my example above the `Solid` would take the place of `{{pattern}}` making the link send the user to `/solid/suit-color`

Comment: Try adding a leading slash to the href and route `href="/{{pattern}}/..."` `router.get('/:pattern/...')`

Comment: still not working. The link removes the `localhost:3000` and I now get `//next-page'. Could this be because the route doesn't know what parameter is being selected because it is not globally accessible? I'm not sure if by click on the link it is actually providing a parameter that can then be used by the routes. Does this sound right?